# Facebook graph API returns only name and id for some websites

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've developed a WordPress plugin for social login using Facebook. 
I'm using the Facebook graph API `/me` to retrieve the user details. My problem is that for some websites, when installed a Facebook login plugin, I'm only getting user ID and name.

```
Array
(
    [name] => John doe
    [id] => 398463877009801
)
```

but same code is working well for some websites as well.

```
Array
(
    [id] => 398463877009801
    [email] => something@gmail.com
    [first_name] => John
    [gender] => male
    [last_name] => Doe
    [link] => https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/398463877009801/
    [locale] => en_US
    [name] => John Doe
    [timezone] => 5.45
    [updated_time] => 2015-05-03T11:24:16+0000
    [verified] => 1
)
```

What might be the possibilities of the errors for the site that is getting only name and id?

Comment: API v2.4 has changed what fields are returned by default. Go read the changelog.

Answer (score 76):

As CBroe already pointed out in the above comment, the Facebook API - newer than version 2.4 - changed the response and the way the requests are being sent.

You **have to specify each field** you want to be returned from the Graph API within your request.

For example, if you want the fields `email` and `name` returned, you must add them inside the request like this:

```
/me?fields=email,name
```

Comment: Hi Razvan 

Thank you so much for your reply.

But I tried already placing the fields values but still i'm not getting what i want. I'm always receving id and name if I place the field attributes or not placing any field attributes. It's so strange behaviour to me because same code is working for most of the sites.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the official php facebook sdk? Can we see some code? Did you ask for the right permissions by specifying the scope?

Comment: I don't know how to send the link of the files here. I'll try to narrate my code
[code]
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user){
       try {// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
      $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
       } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      error_log($e);
      $user = null;
       }
    }

print_r($user_profile );
[/code]

Comment: First of all upgrade your SDK to this version [NEW FACEBOOK SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4), as it seems to me that you are running an outdated version and follow this self-explanatory [EXAMPLE](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/5.0-dev/docs/example_facebook_login.fbmd). Note the $permissions array.

Comment: I really can't make the new facebook sdk work for me. Can you please show me some examples how to implement these example codes.

Comment: Finally I was able to fix the issue after updating the facebook php sdk.

Comment: Thank You!!!! buddy, I fixed this issue at my end, I used 3rd party plugin to manage the Facebook API. below is my call

'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,email,gender,link,locale,timezone,updated_time,verified'